# What is the response of Trinitarians to these ten assertions?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, authority, godhead

1. **It makes someone other than God also have the title of "God".** (Exodus 20:3)

There cannot be a capital-G God beneath the capital-G God—only a lowercase god.

The capital-G God is the highest authority and source of all things. The Trinity therefore violates the Shema and the 1st Commandment; to worship no other gods but the only true God, who is just one being.

2. **It violates God's headship of authority.** (1 Corinthians 11:3)

{Female < Male < Christ < God} is violated by making Jesus equal with Father God, thereby unleashing a domino effect which further results in man becoming equal with Christ, and woman becoming equal with man; a catastrophic annihilation of God's created order.

3. **It destroys the term "only begotten" (monogenes) in Greek.** (John 3:18)

In contradiction of correct doctrine that Jesus was created (begotten) by the Father God on Day 1 of creation, Jesus is instead claimed to be co-eternal with the Father, nullifying Christ's terms of "only begotten", "firstborn of creation", and "first of his works of old".

In a terrible attempt to explain this off, Trinitarians instead replace it with the illogical term "eternally begotten". "Eternally begotten" is a nonsensical term which is fielded to justify their blasphemous theology and discredit "only begotten" (monogenes in Greek). In recent times, Trinitarian translators have even gone so far as to remove the term "begotten" to leave it as "only Son", in a sinister attempt to hide the fact that Jesus was created by God on Day 1 of Creation as his only-begotten Son. They do this to make Jesus be God and co-eternal alongside God our Father.

4. **It disregards what a mediator is.** (1 Timothy 2:5)

A mediator is someone who intercedes between two people. The mediator who intercedes cannot be the person who sent him, or the person he was sent to mediate for, otherwise it is not mediation. Jesus is not God, but the Son of God and Son of Man. God sent his Son to intercede on behalf of humanity to draw out the chosen elect from the foundation of the world. God sent his Son to be our Mediator. Jesus was an immortal god, yet emptied himself and came down into mortal human flesh to intercede on our behalf and save us from sin and the death.

5. **It ignores that God cannot die.** (1 Timothy 1:17)

The scriptures make it clear that God cannot die. Jesus died, but God his Father resurrected him from the dead, just as God will resurrect us from the dead if we believe in Him and his Son. Jesus is not God because Jesus died. In fact, Jesus said that God abandoned him while he was dying on the cross. This was to fulfill Christ's mission of taking on the curse of our sin and deserved abandonment from God on our behalf, to save us from this world.

6. **It forgets that God can never be tempted.** (James 1:13)

The scriptures also clearly tell us that Jesus was tempted by the devil Satan, but that he did not fall for the temptations. Jesus felt the pangs of temptation, but he fended them off in the Spirit of God. Likewise, we can fend off temptations by remaining in the Spirit of God. The scriptures tell us that God can never be tempted, yet Jesus was tempted on our behalf. Jesus is therefore not God.

7. **It contradicts itself by wrongly stating that an angel is God.** (Psalm 104:4)

Jesus was pre-incarnate and post-incarnate as the Chief Angel of God as the only-begotten Son of God. Nevertheless, Trinitarians state that Jesus was God despite admitting that Jesus was the "Angel of the LORD" throughout the Old Testament. The issue is that God is not an angel, and will never be an angel, because angels are created by God, but God is eternal and uncreated. It is certainly true that the Angel of the LORD is the glorified Son of God, but the Angel of the LORD is absolutely not God because he is the mediating angel and viceroy of God's Presence!

8. **It discredits the fact that only God's will alone is accomplished.** (Ephesians 1:11)

Jesus plainly told us that he came to do not his own will, but the will of God who sent him. Jesus was teaching us humility when he told us to hold others above ourselves, and to do the will of God alone and not our own will. "Not my will be done, but your will be done". "Let your will be done on earth as it is in heaven". Jesus is not God because Jesus was doing the will of his God, who is our God, and his Father, who is our Father. Only God's will is done, not the will of anyone else.

9. **It disregards that only God is omniscient and nobody else.** (Matthew 24:36)

Jesus said that nobody knows the Day or the Hour, neither the Son, but the Father God only. Some take John 16:30 and John 21:17 to mean that Jesus "knows all things", but these passages simply state that Jesus knew everything that was necessary to know about the particular topics at hand, namely love and judgement. Only the Father God is truly omniscient and knows all things, as all things have come from him alone.

10. **It makes God not good despite God being described as only good.** (Mark 10:18)

When Jesus was called "good teacher", he responded by rebuking it and saying that nobody is good except God alone. This implies that Jesus is not God, and that he is not truly good, as only his Father God is truly good, because God is the source all things, especially all that is good. Psalm 100:5 says that God is good, forever.

Comment: Blasphemous from whose perspective? Questions should be scoped to a particular denomination/viewpoint.

Comment: "It makes something other than God also have the title of "God"" Trinitarians do not believe or teach this. I don't understand how you could even think that was the case. Trinitarians don't believe your other two reasons either, but they're more understandable misunderstandings.

Comment: Meanwhile, you need to [edit] this to make your language respectful. These are code of conduct violations and are not acceptable: "In a pathetic attempt to explain this of", ""Eternally begotten" is an utterly nonsensical term".

Comment: I suggest you take the time to learn more about what Trinitarians actually believe and teach before writing diatribes against them. Most of this site non-Trinitarian members would be aware that Trinitarians would agree with most of these arguments - because Trinitarians don't believe what you think they do!

Comment: I see you have made numerous edits to your original question, and have slightly modified claims and opinions you hold.  Nonetheless, your question sounds more like a rant against the Trinity doctrine.  For that reason, I am down-voting your question.

Comment: Down-voted. Voted to close as opinion based. Flagged for Moderator attention as the question is against Stack Exchange's Code of Conduct. This is exactly the same accusation leveled at Jesus by the Jews and is the reason they arrested him and delivered him to the Romans to be crucified.

Comment: They were accusing him correctly, as Jesus was declaring himself to be like God as a god. Nevertheless, the Jews did not want to admit that he was their Messiah, sent from God to circumcise the heart.

Comment: maybe you could try listing your 10 points, and ask how a trinitarian might address these points? [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth), there are many denominations and they have different interpretations of the bible. Calling a group blasphemous based on your perspective isn't conductive to respectful discourse.

Comment: @depperm - done. I just listed the 10 points so you or anyone can address them.

Comment: @depperm 10 points is way too many to cover in a single question.  It was certainly nice of Joshua to abide your suggestion, but it's not gonna help the question.  Joshua, please ask individual questions and scan the site to see if they've already been asked because we close all duplicate questions and there's no need to ask a question that is going to be closed.

Comment: I do agree with the last point that when Jesus rejected being good , he denied being good because we say that God is good all the time and all the time God is good and that is his nature, wow.

Answer (score 1):

The short and correct answer to this question (if it really is a question) is: no.

Your “reasons” are arguments without context and therefore can never prove anything. Proof is only proof within a certain context. I could prove the sum of the corners of a triangle make exactly 180 degrees, but only in euclidean space. But that proof would fail if our triangle lies on a sphere.

So, if your context is “I am always right, and the Trinity doctrine is blasphemous” then your arguments are incredibly strong. If however your context is mainstream Christianity, then obviously you are wrong and your arguments can be countered.

The thing is, this is not a debate-site. So please, be clear about your question. I will be more than happy to answer whatever I can, and most people here are too.

Comment: In the second sentence in the second paragraph, is it supposed to be "prove that some..." or "prove the sum"?

Comment: Thank you :) autocorrect + non native speaker…